# Answering a protected question on a different site

Tags: discussion, reputation, protected-questions

I'm mainly a Stack Overflower, but sometimes stray to darker sides of Stack Exchange. I get the customary 100 rep bump since I'm a 'trusted member'. However, on a recent site I visited ([English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com)), I couldn't post an answer to a protected question because I didn't have 10 rep points on that specific site. So what was the purpose in giving me the 100 rep bump? More of a curiosity than anything and wondering if that's intentional or an oversight.

Comment: You can't answer closed questions *anywhere*. Did you mean *protected* instead?

Comment: And no, it is not an oversight, that limit is quite deliberate.